# is there a way to avoid nested loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm given two different data and I'm wondering if there is a way to get specific data without using nested loop

```
firstdata = [[["key"],["value"]],
              [[2],["two"]],
              [[3],["three"]]]
seconddata = [[[key],["artimatic"]],
               [[2],["0+2"]],
               [[2],["1+1"]],
               [[3],["0+3"]],
               [[3],["1+2"]],
               [[3],["2+1"]]]
 //nested loop solution would look like this
 for x in firstdata:
     for y in seconddata:
         print(x[1])
         if x[0]==y[0]:
             print(y)
```

Is there an alternative solution that I can loop the seconddata without using nested loop?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? If a key exists in first Data, then you want to print the values of the same key in second Data? If so, use dictionaries, they use Hash Tables and bring down complexity to O(1).

Comment: @anand_v.singh you got it right thats what im trying to do. How do I go about that...

Comment: for now its only two data but im going to do that over 5 data sets

Comment: and lets not forget im working with a list of a list

Comment: Rather than keeping them as list where the 0th element in the list is the key, use a dictionary, but only do that if keys are unique.

Comment: You can convert list to a dictionary

Comment: for the second data keys cant be unique ... i have to work against that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191631/discussion-between-anand-v-singh-and-toy-moy).

Comment: Check my answer below, thanks to the input from @anand_v.singh

Answer (score 1):

**Ok I am assuming Data Structure of firstdata and seconddata will be same:

```
firstdata_dict = {x[0][0]: x[1][0] for x in firstdata}
seconddata_dict = {}

for data in seconddata:

   if not seconddata_dict.has_key(data[0][0]):
       seconddata_dict[data[0][0]] = []
   seconddata_dict[data[0][0]].append(data[1][0])

for key, value in firstdata_dict.items():
    if seconddata_dict.get(key):
       # key match add your algo 
       print seconddata_dict[key]

Output:
['0+2', '1+1']
['0+3', '1+2', '2+1']
['artimatic']
```

Comment: SecondData has reapeated keys, thus can't be converted to dictionary, hence this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Start by converting the list to a dictionary as so. Here the keys are the numbers 2 and 3, and values are list of strings associated to a specific key in the list

```
def convert_to_dct(lst):

    dct = {}
    for x in lst:
        for i in range(len(x)):
            key = x[0][0]
            value = x[1][0]
            if key in dct:
                dct[key].append(value)
            else:
                dct[key] = []

    return dct
```

This function converts the list as follows

```
firstdata = [[["key"],["value"]],
              [[2],["two"]],
              [[3],["three"]]]
seconddata = [[["key"],["artimatic"]],
               [[2],["0+2"]],
               [[2],["1+1"]],
               [[3],["0+3"]],
               [[3],["1+2"]],
               [[3],["2+1"]]]

firstdict = convert_to_dct(firstdata)
seconddict = convert_to_dct(seconddata)

print(firstdict)
print(seconddict)
#{'key': ['value'], 2: ['two'], 3: ['three']}
#{'key': ['artimatic'], 2: ['0+2', '1+1', '1+1'], 3: ['0+3', '1+2', '1+2', '2+1', '2+1']}
```

Then to get your final result, do

```
for key in firstdict.keys():
   if key in seconddict.keys():
       print(seconddict[key])
#['artimatic']
#['0+2', '1+1', '1+1']
#['0+3', '1+2', '1+2', '2+1', '2+1']
```

Comment: You would need to pre-process the list to make it to a dictionary, for which you need a nested loop. But there is no nested loop when you find elements in the dict

Comment: @ToyMoy the nested loop is iterating the elements in the each element of the first list, and is vastly different from the one you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Devesh though convert to dict works, it is already known that firstData doesn't contain duplicate keys, you can leverage that :)

Comment: Well then we need to change the logic for that specific case, but here both cases are handled in one function

Comment: Oh, you haven't understood the question then, the second data can't be converted to dict as it will have repeated keys, and all cases of repeated keys have to be managed. you are suppressing repeated keys in the second data, that is not the desired characterstics

Comment: Updated accordingly! The value is a list which can contain repeated items for the same key

Comment: Still not the answer OP is looking for, No need to convert second data to dict. It was getting a bit too long to explain so I added the answer :)

Comment: Sure, I thought representing the answer as a list, for easier representation. I will let OP decide further

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the two answers understand the question correctly, so here you go:

Create your data

```
firstData = [[["key"],["value"]],
              [[2],["two"]],
              [[3],["three"]]]
secondData = [[['key'],["artimatic"]],
               [[2],["0+2"]],
               [[2],["1+1"]],
               [[3],["0+3"]],
               [[3],["1+2"]],
               [[3],["2+1"]]]
```

Then

```
firstdata_dict = {x[0][0]: x[1][0] for x in firstData} #Creates the dictionary of first Data
```

Then do the computation

```
for element in secondData:
  if (element[0][0] in firstdata_dict): #Checks in a hashMap and is thus done in O(1) generally
    print(element)
```